# getting package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist error while packaging app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am quite new in Spring world. I have developed a DAO using Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4.1.9 but I have noticed a strange thing.

All the used dependencies related to Spring belong to the 3.2.1 version, except that related to the **spring-aop** module. For this module I have to use the 3.2.0 version because if I use the 3.2.1 in the dao class implementation don't find this import: **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional**

This is my original **pom.xml** file (that work well):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.andrea.myexample</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateOnSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HibernateOnSpring</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dipendenze di Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dipendenze per AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dipendenze per Persistence Managment -->

        <dependency>    <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>    <!-- Hibernate -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and this is my **PersonDAOImpl** class (the class that implement my concrete DAO):

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    // Factory per la creazione delle sessioni di Hibernate:
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // CREATE CRUD Operation:
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Integer addPerson(Person p) {

        System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer personID = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            personID = (Integer) session.save(p);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return personID;

    }

    // READ CRUD Operation (legge un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
    public Person getById(int id) {

        System.out.println("Inside getById()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;          
        Person retrievedPerson = null;  

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            retrievedPerson = (Person) session.get(Person.class, id);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {                 
            session.close();
        }

        return retrievedPerson;
    }

    // READ CRUD Operation (recupera la lista di tutti i record nella tabella):
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getPersonsList() {

        System.out.println("Inside getPersonsList()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Person> personList = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
            personList = criteria.list();
            System.out.println("personList: " + personList);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return personList;
    }

    // DELETE CRUD Operation (elimina un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
    public void delete(int id) {

        System.out.println("Inside delete()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Person personToDelete = getById(id);
            session.delete(personToDelete);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Person personToUpdate) {

        System.out.println("Inside update()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Insite update() method try");
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(personToUpdate);

            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }   

    }

}
```

The problem is that if I use the **3.2.1** version for the **spring-aop** module instead of the **3.2.0** changing this dependency in this way:

```
    <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run Maven ---> Maven Install happen the compilation fail and return the following error message:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[15,49] error: package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[27,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class PersonDAOImpl
/home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[128,2] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.288s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 08 13:19:23 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project HibernateOnSpring: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[15,49] error: package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[27,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class PersonDAOImpl
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/ws/HibernateOnSpring/src/main/java/org/andrea/myexample/HibernateOnSpring/dao/PersonDAOImpl.java:[128,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Andin the **PersonDAOImpl** happen that don't find the following imported class:

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Why I have this problem if I try to use the 3.2.1 version of spring-orm module? How can I solve to use it?

Answer (score 26):

The package `org.springframework.transaction` is provided by the `spring-tx` artifact. Add the following to your pom.xml and do maven update, that should do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In gradle, just add the line :  compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE' Replace "3.2.2.RELEASE" with the version you are using of course

Answer (score 2):

Try using all spring related dependencies of same version. 
I guess org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional is present in spring 3.2.0.
So this should not be issue. Include spring-tx dependency for @Transactionl to work.

Comment: I have solved adding spring-tx and spring-jdbc dependencies both belong to 3.2.1 version...but I don't understand why it work when I have not them using 3.2.0 version of spring-orm module...

Comment: I added the dependency and indeed, that does the job. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation is in the spring-tx module. Include version 3.2.1 of that, and always make sure to use the same version of all Spring modules.