# Please configure Spring Facet for modules:

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, intellij-14

What am I supposed to do here? Clicking 'spring-accessing-data-with-jpa' Opens up 'Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules'.

[image]

Comment: This might be a duplicate, I answered very similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32861715/1291150

Comment: I agree it might be.