# Importing to IntelliJ - Error package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Dear Stackoverflow Community, I have the following problem with my spring boot starter application. I imported the starter project as a new maven project into IntelliJ. But IntelliJ does not find the dependencies I specified in the pom.

Image of my Application Class:
[image]

If I try to run the project I get the following error message.

Image of the Error Message:
[image]

I already tried everything from re-installing IntelliJ to re-importing the project or redownloading the dependencies. I simply dont know why IntelliJ doesn´t find the dependencies.

My pom.xml looks as following

Image of my pom.xml:
[image]

The first time I tried to edit the `pom.xml` it said to me "this file does not belong to the project". Maybe this might be one reason.

Running the whole thing with 'mvn install' or 'mvn clean verify' works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but it did not work out when i tried without "importing as maven". I am going to try it with a new project if I get the same error.

Comment: Go to the project settings (the drop down located at the top right corner in intelliji). Make sure that your application is selected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package org.springframework.boot does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847951/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how my IntelliJ settings for spring boot application looks like

**Click open -> browse your workspace -> and select POM.xml file**
[image: Click open -> browse your workspace -> and select POM.xml file]

**Check this in your intelliJ settings**
[image: Check this in your intelliJ settings]

**Do this too** [`Settings --> Maven --> Importing`]

[image]

Comment: I tried it like you described. My IntelliJ said "Non-managed pom.xml file found". I clicked "add as maven project" but the error still persists

Comment: See the right (green tick) answer and first comment of that answer in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven

Comment: If that doesn't fix the issue try to replace your maven pox xml file - by creating a new one https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Edited my post to add that screenshot too

Comment: Thanks i am going to read through those two articles. I just wanted to mention that 'mvn install' creates a runnable jar file

Comment: We managed to get it running by creating a new project with spring initializr like we did the first time. I dont know why it works now

Comment: Great to know !

Answer (score 16):

Had the same problem. I have tried everything: invalidating cache, deleting the whole .m2 folder, changing settings, reloding the project, nothing helped.

**The solution for me was to delete the .iml files** which are IntelliJ module files used for keeping module configuration. After reopening the project it worked.

The idea was not mine, I found the hint here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203365204--package-does-not-exist-error-despite-autocomplete-being-aware-of-them

Comment: Was able to do a successful "mvn clean install" using terminal.  But was getting error in IntelliJ. So I deleted .idea folder from repo, loaded project again in intellij and it worked :)

Answer (score 14):

Try this and then build: mvn -U idea:idea

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your answer *Try this and then build: mvn -U idea:idea* – please elaborate what you refer to by *try this*. Also when answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for the green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to it. You're not explaining why your answer solves the problem. Please refer to this [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details.

Comment: Thanks @wshow for your answer. Do you know how automatically run this command ? Because I have to fix this everytime I add a maven dependency.

Comment: I use this and it worked! thank you @wshow.   For the others wondering write it exactly as it is!

Comment: For anyone wondering what does this mvn build does: it installs all the plugins and downloads all dependencies, as well as setting project wise files.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes your workspace could get corrupted.
In my case, I tried to Reload the project and it worked

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in my case changed JDK version in Maven importer from JDK 11 to my local JDK version 1.8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps, your problem should be solved. You just need to add `Spring-framework-starter-web` and `Spring-framework-starter-tester` from your `pom.xml` file.

1. Got to generate(<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>)
2. Add dependencies
3. Search "springframwork"
4. Add...

[Here is the link](https://exerror.com/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist/)

Answer (score 1):

For me this method worked, seems dependencies are not downloaded due to wrong Maven home path.

settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Maven >> change maven home path from "use maven wrapper" to Bundled(Maven 3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.  My solution was to remove all dependencies from the pom, reload via maven -> Reload All Maven Projects.  Run mvn compile.  Add dependencies back to the pom, maven -> Reload All Maven Projects.  Run mvn compile.
Now the Intellij build works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Maven's `JDK for importing` option from **Project JDK** to the Path variable for Java on your machine.

You can get to this by going to `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Importing`. Scroll down to the bottom and look for `JDK for importing:`. Select from the list the **path variable** for JAVA.

[image: Above image shows how to change the JDK for importing with Maven.]

For Windows users, `JAVA_HOME` should be an option in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the project as maven project helped .

Answer (score 0):

For my case, had to change the maven importing settings from the JRE path to the JDK path on my local machine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , only to find out I made a very careless mistake of having  2 versions of IntelliJ.

I uninstalled all of them and did a new installation, now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. I removed all folder and file in this path below:

> C:\Users\Lenovo.m2\repository

I opend the intelij IDE and opened the maven:

> View -> Tool Windows ->Maven

and clicked on the "Reload All Maven Project". it downloaded the dependencies and run the project again. check before the path below:

> C:\Users\Lenovo.m2\repository

it should download all the dependencies.

I hope it is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I was using IntelliJ IDEA.
In my case I deleted .idea folder and re-build the project then it worked well.