# SpringBoot cannot be found IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm struggling to make my setup to work Intellij + SpringBoot.
I downloaded a regular pom.xml from spring initializr.
When i build/run the project it does not find spring boot dependencies, but running `mvnw spring-boot:run` works fine.
So i assume it might be something with IntelliJ, but simply can't figure it out.
NOTE: This is a new installation of everything. And using

> openjdk version "1.8.0_252" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>   (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

My Maven Settings are default

[image: Maven Settings]

Am I escaping something ?
BR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sergio</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Errors

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'demo'
Information:javac 1.8.0_252 was used to compile java sources
Information:18/04/2020 02:42 - Build completed with 18 errors and 0 warnings in 4 s 255 ms
C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\com\sergio\demo\DemoApplication.java
    Error:Error:line (3)java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
    Error:Error:line (4)java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
    Error:Error:line (5)java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
    Error:Error:line (6)java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
    Error:Error:line (8)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
    Error:Error:line (12)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class com.sergio.demo.DemoApplication
C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\demo\src\main\java\com\sergio\demo\Entity\AnimeNew.java
    Error:Error:line (4)java: package lombok does not exist
    Error:Error:line (5)java: package lombok does not exist
    Error:Error:line (6)java: package lombok does not exist
    Error:Error:line (7)java: package lombok does not exist
    Error:Error:line (14)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Getter
    Error:Error:line (15)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RequiredArgsConstructor
    Error:Error:line (18)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
    Error:Error:line (19)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
    Error:Error:line (20)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
    Error:Error:line (21)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
    Error:Error:line (22)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
    Error:Error:line (23)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class com.sergio.demo.Entity.AnimeNew
```

EDIT 1:
Got the full log from intelij https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NpIJg-OYi7PGfWMNAVeSDBakU9bOaB20/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to build on plain command line first...and lets see if there are errors or not...

Comment: same error cannot be found

Comment: can you post the log output during the build...best would be the full output..

Comment: the log output is the same as  above on my original post Errors

Comment: Have you imported your project as a Maven project?

Comment: can you see these imports under External Libraries? If not then those are not imported under the project. You might want to re-import the dependecies,

Comment: @shivanithakur they are

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I created it with the inteliji plugin for springboot so i assume so.

Comment: try deleting those packages from .m2 folder and reimport them.

Comment: @shivanithakur still not working :(

Comment: If command line Maven build also fails - this means the Maven is unable to download these libraries form the Maven repository. You have the `parent` section declared in pom.xml. Then you need to make sure this parent Maven project must exist in your local repository. Check your network configuration: if you have proxy, make sure it is configured in Maven. Also verify you have

Comment: Have you tried reimporting the project (refresh button on the Maven tab in IntelliJ)?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing lombok in intellij IDEA:

1. Go to File > Settings > Plugins.
2. Click on Browse repositories...
3. Search for Lombok Plugin.
4. Click on Install plugin.
5. Restart IntelliJ IDEA.

If that still doesn't work, try:
`File->Invalidate cache and restart` and then build your project.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I had it installed also used that invalidate cache, i can see them under the external libraries.

Comment: it is almost obvious that your lombok plugin is not recognized in the project. You can try uninstalling the lombok plugin and re-install that again and follow that procedures.  Moreover, try updating your IDEA version if possible

Comment: tried and still got the same problem. It's not only lombok but also spring. removing everything and just leaving the application itself i also get error

Comment: I see!
weird problem...btw, did you tried updating intellij version?

Comment: Yes, it was a fresh install and updated yesterday. Guess java just hates me :D

Comment: Don't know what to say, can check this if helps  [package org.springframework.boot does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847951/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist)