# Error: java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I made a simple application today that gives me a few errors when I run. I made another application very similar to this one yesterday which was working fine but is now broke as well

I am getting these errors:

```
Error:(4, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
Error:(5, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
Error:(6, 35) java: package org.springframework.context does not exist
Error:(9, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
Error:(13, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ApplicationContext
  location: class com.example.dependencyinjection.DependencyInjectionApplication
Error:(13, 42) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class com.example.dependencyinjection.DependencyInjectionApplication
Error:(3, 38) java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
Error:(5, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Controller
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-injection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dependency-injection</name>
    <description>Example project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried:

- Reimporting all Maven projects
- Generating sources and updating all folders for all projects
- Creating a new project using Spring initalizer
- Checking settings path for settings.xml
- Deleting the .m2 folder
- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Reopening the project with auto imports on
- Removing/altering VM options for imports
- Forcing Intellij to reread all maven dependencies
- Confirming that the dependencies are in Modules
- Updating Maven repositories
- Many different pom.xml configurations
- Cloning and building a project which is known to work
- Changing Maven's default executable
- Turning auto sync completely off
- Reinstalling Intellij

Any other ideas?

Comment: Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239150#focus=streamItem-27-4117814.0-0 help? IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 and 2020.1.1 versions are affected by a bug specific to Maven projects where build fill fail from the IDE. You can also use 2019.3.x release from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html as a workaround.

Comment: Adding the path.macros.xml worked! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package org.springframework.boot does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847951/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237320) in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 and 2020.1.1 versions (will be fixed in 2020.1.2) where Maven dependencies are not found by the compiler because the path macros are not resolved properly.

You can use [a workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239150#focus=streamItem-27-4117814.0-0) until the fix is released or [downgrade to 2019.3.x version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

The workaround is to override the default setting for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Local repository** (set it to some other value different from default).

Or else make sure the `path.macros.xml` file exists in [`<IDE config>`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory)`/options` directory with the following content:

```
<application>
  <component name="PathMacrosImpl">
   <macro name="KOTLIN_BUNDLED" value="<path to IDE installation>\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" />
    <macro name="MAVEN_REPOSITORY" value="<path to>/.m2/repository" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Where the `<path to>/.m2/repository` - is the path to your local Maven repository and the `<path to IDE installation>` - the path to IDE installation home.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Mine worked by changing the `Maven Home Path` to my locally installed maven, instead of using the default Wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

in my case have changed Maven import JDK version.
In latest version in intellij its pointing to JDK11. then changes to my internal JDK version resolved issue[image]

Answer (score 2):

I followed these steps and my project built successfully.

1. run `mvn clean`
2. go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Repositories and update them.(not sure if this is nessasary)
3. Refresh your maven dependancies by clicking the reload button on the maven tab.
4. Go to build and click on **re**build project.

Answer (score 1):

Add spring-boot-starter-web dependency to your POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm certain that it doesn't have anything to do with the pom file

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need the `spring-boot` dependency in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve the issue by simply restarting my laptop having all required dependencies and JDK setup.