# Error:(4, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I get this error when I build my project:

```
Error:(3, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
Error:(4, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
Error:(6, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
Error:(10, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class com.victorhez.ecommercespringboot.EcommerceSpringBootApplication
```

My POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.victorhez</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-spring-boot</name>
    <description>Ecommerce Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

These dependencies are showing me errors:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
```

My Java File

```
package com.victorhez.ecommercespringboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please help    me with this issue

Comment: did you do a mvn clean install?

Answer (score -2):

The above question is duplicate please refer [package org.springframework.boot does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847951/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist) and try to follow all the steps mentioned in the thread, I hope that will help.

Also, try basic steps and re-import your module in eclipse and check to build automatically and run mvn clean install, also go to .M2 location and search for the jar.

Comment: If you find a question which contains the answer, please vote to close as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: Not answered, mine is not commented as the one in the link was commented

Comment: @Victorhez You mean you tried the steps mentioned in the above thread still having the issues?

Comment: Resolved by creating a new project