# Maven - package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I looked at other topics such as this one:
[package org.springframework.boot does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847951/package-org-springframework-boot-does-not-exist)

But none of the solutions helped me.
Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <description>My App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why am i getting this error when trying to run `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line?

Comment: No, that's where I'm trying to build.

Comment: And what is the error message but not only excerpts please add the full output

Answer (score 1):

if you recently moved to v2.4.5, I'd try to update the remote maven central (in IntelliJ IDEA it's a one-button-click action) - maven probably don't know about this version and won't download it

Comment: Sorry, i thought it worked but i didn't :(